# How to correct the query statement (string interpolation) in the Datadog dashboard?

Tags: datadog

I want to be able to parameterised my datadog dashboard.

I have already introduced a template variable `flavor` which to indicate if it is `dev` or `prod` environment.

What I wish to achieve is to switch data from one environment o another when I select a different environment (e.g. from `dev-db-master` to `prod-db-master`). The string interpolation is necessary because I want to display multiple time series within a single chart.

[image]

However the chart is basically blank

[image]

The Json tab also shows a pink background which indicates either the json is malformed or the query is too complex.

My goal is to be able to, by changing the template variable `flavor`,

I can change a group of time series from, says, **'dev-db-master', 'dev-db1-master' and 'dev-db2-master'** to **'prod-db-master', 'prod-db1-master' and 'prod-db2-master'**.

Can you suggest a way to construct a string with a template variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the template variables [doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/#pagetitle)?

You could select:

- Name: Name,
- Tag or Attribute: name,
- Default Value: dev-db-master

Then you'll be able to replace your `{name:$flavor-db-master}` with `{$Name}`

Otherwise, if you actually wants the value of the template variable you have to use `$flavor.value`. I advise to use a not widget to check the actual behavior.

EDIT:

This kind of setup is not the recommended. It would be better to set two tags on your database:

- `env:dev` or `env:prod`
- `dbname:db1-master` or `dbname:db2-master`.

You would then have a unique selection of tags, `env:dev,dbname:db1-master`. It would then be easy to have a query such as:

```
"q": "avg:aws.rds.bin_log_disk_usage{$Env,dbname:db1-master}"
```

Comment: I am using a template variable already; I have updated the question to explain my situation better.

Comment: I think that this kind of setup is not the most appropriate. It would be better to set two tags on your database: `env:dev` or `env:prod` and another such as `dbname:db1-master` or `dbname:db2-master`. You would then have a unique selection of tags, `env:dev,dbname:db1-master`.

I've tested a similar setup as yours and I can see some issue. So I would rather recommend what I mention above if possible. 

To do more testing, you can add a "Notes and Links" widget and add this as content: `name:$flavor.value` you'll be able to understand better the variable behaviors.